# What is the physical property used in choosing the separation techniques for CaCO3 and KCl and NH4Cl

Tags: separation-techniques

I've been scrolling through a chemistry past question but when I came across this I tried to solve it but it keeps confusing me

Comment: Please write your question in the [Body box](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gkAVe.png). Your question should be clear even without the title. (Especially, do not write your whole question in the title and then put “title says it all” in the body.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ce{CaCO3}$ is not soluble in water. Both $\ce{KCl}$ and $\ce{NH4Cl}$ are soluble in water. When heated $\ce{NH4Cl}$ sublimes at 335 °C. At this temperature, $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $\ce{KCl}$ are not modified. $\ce{CaCO3}$ is decomposed in $\ce{CaO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ at 825 °C.